# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor execution strategy

Tags: spring, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using spring's abstraction ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in order to execute tasks using threads.

The execute method described as (java doc):

Execute the given task.
The call might return immediately if the implementation uses an asynchronous execution strategy, or might block in the case of synchronous execution.

Got 2 questions:

1. Where can the execution strategy be configured?
2. If the execution strategy is set to "synchronous", how can it serve me? It seems weird to use an executor that works synchronously.

Comment: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  implements AsyncTaskExecutor, As per docs: "Implementing this interface also indicates that the TaskExecutor.execute(Runnable) method will not execute its Runnable in the caller's thread but rather asynchronously in some other thread"

Comment: `execute(Runnable)` is part of TaskExecutor and not `AsyncTaskExecutor`. isn't it? How do we really know which execution Strategy is really used by the `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`